# Redirect https to http without causing client errors

Tags: http, https, nginx

I have developed an app which talks to a server over https.

I recently discovered that my certificate has expired, and now the app refuses to talk to the server.

```
NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9814)
```

How can I do a quick fix so that my app will work (insecurely), until I can renew my certificate?

I tried the following, but the app still protests (as does browsers).

```
  server {
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/server.key; 
    listen 443;
    rewrite ^ http://$http_host$uri permanent; # temporary workaround
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fundamentally impossible.

TLS handshake and all checks are done before any request will be sent. This is what "security" is about.

Comment: So the morale is: Don't let your certificates expire. It will cause instant downtime on your online services until you can renew your certificates!

Answer (score 0):

convert the ssl server to normal server and create a new ssl server that redirects all requests

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name whatever.com www.whatever.com;
    return 301 http://$http_host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name whatever.com www.whatever.com;
    # old configurations from the ssl server
}
```